# How can I efficiently split an array into its associative key arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

How can I split a single array into it's sub-keys?

```
$arr = array(
             0 => array(
                        'foo' => '1',
                        'bar' => 'A'
                       ),
             1 => array(
                        'foo' => '2',
                        'bar' => 'B'
                       ),
             2 => array(
                        'foo' => '3',
                        'bar' => 'C'
                       )
            );
```

What is the most efficient way to return an array of foo and bar separately?

I need to get here:

```
$foo = array('1','2','3');
$bar = array('A','B','C');
```

I'm hoping there's a clever way to do this using `array_map` or something similar.  Any ideas?

Or do I have to loop through and build each array that way?  Something like:

```
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $foo[] = $v['foo'];
    $bar[] = $v['bar'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a lucky coincidence, I needed to do almost the exact same thing earlier today. You can use `array_map()` in combination with `array_shift()`:

```
$foo = array_map('array_shift', &$arr);
$bar = array_map('array_shift', &$arr);
```

Note that `$arr` is passed by reference! If you don't do that, then each time it would return the contents of `$arr[<index>]['foo']`. However, again because of the reference - you won't be able to reuse `$arr`, so if you need to do that - copy it first.

The downside is that your array keys need to be ordered in the same way as in your example, because `array_shift()` doesn't actually know what the key is. It will NOT work on the following array:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'foo' => '1',
        'bar' => 'A'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'bar' => 'B',
        'foo' => '2'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'foo' => '3',
        'bar' => 'C'
    )
);
```

**Update:**

After reading the comments, it became evident that my solution triggers `E_DEPRECATED` warnings for call-time-pass-by-reference. Here's the suggested (and accepted as an answer) alternative by @Baba, which takes advantage of the two needed keys being the first and last elements of the second-dimension arrays:

```
$foo = array_map('array_shift', $arr);
$bar = array_map('array_pop', $arr);
```

Comment: I really don't think had the same issues if not you would have known that it would generate error http://3v4l.org/BEmL1

Comment: Good catch! I guess I should update my php.ini. Though, I said almost - what I needed to do is to only get 'foo', so passing by reference wasn't needed.

Comment: Baba!  It works.  Edited Narf's answer as recommended.  Well done.

Comment: I have no problem with my answer being edited, but that particular edit invalidates ALL of what I've written, except for the code blocks - not nice!

Comment: Thanks Narf.  Sorry about that.  Your update is more clear.  Thanks again.  Really helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = array();

foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
    foreach($val as $k=>$v) {
        $n[$k][] = $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) will combine scalar values with the same key into an array. e.g.:

```
array_merge_recursive(array('a',1), array('b',2)) === array(array('a','b'),array(1,2));
```

You can use this property to simply apply `array_merge_recursive` over each array in your array as a separate argument:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arr);
```

You will get this result:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
    2 => '3',
  ),
  'bar' => 
  array (
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C',
  ),
)
```

It won't even be confused by keys in different order.

**However, every merged value must be scalar!** Arrays will be merged instead of added as a sub-array:

```
array_merge_recursive(array(1), array(array(2)) === array(array(1,2))
```

It does *not* produce `array(array(1, array(2)))`!