# How to convert this PHP array ina working price calculation?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Here comes the tricky part
In a rent application, I have arrays like this (of course array size and values may vary):

```
$dates = array();
// each "pipe" | is an item for visual help
$dates['2013-07-15'] = 2; // ||
$dates['2013-07-16'] = 2; // ||
$dates['2013-07-17'] = 5; // |||||
$dates['2013-07-18'] = 3; // |||
$dates['2013-07-19'] = 4; // ||||
$dates['2013-07-20'] = 2; // ||
$dates['2013-07-21'] = 1; // |
```

The keys are the rent days, and the values are the # of items rent by a user for a specific product

Days are all consecutive (I yet grouped adjacent days with [another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729552))

5 consecutive days are considered a "working week", and special price applies: let's say D is the daily price and W is the weekly price

As you can see, in this example a total of 5 items are rent for the dates' range:

1. item 1 for 1 week and 2 spare days (15-16-17-18-19-20-21)
   echo total price: 1*W + 2*D
2. item 2 for 1 week and 1 spare day (15-16-17-18-19-20)
   echo total price: 1*W + 1*D
3. item 3 for 3 spare days (17-18-19)
   echo total price: 0*W + 3*D
4. item 4 for 2 spare days (17-19)
   echo total price: 0*W + 2*D
5. item 5 for 1 day (17)
   echo total price: 0*W + 1*D

... and sum all of the above

Ok, so far so good: I can express the concept in words

But... how to translate this into a script? Really difficult to me!

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: to clarify, values for each array item represents the number of items of that specific product rent by user; let's say product is "Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X" and there are 10 items in the shop's stock; the cleaning company "Your-Clean-House inc." got a big deal and, in this case, is going to rent:

- 2 "Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X" on 2013-07-15
- 2 "Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X" on 2013-07-16
- 5 "Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X" on 2013-07-17
- etc...

Oozel answer make sense! In order to work with my example, I just have to slightly modify his script like this:

```
foreach ($dates as $items){
    for ($i=1; $i<=$items; $i++){
        ... 
    }
}
```

@oozel: I have a number (and not an array of items) 'cause of the specific UI

Oversemplifying:

```
Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X
Calendar
July 2013
...
<td>
    15<br>
    <input type="checkbox" title="Activate this day" value="2013-07-15">
    <select title="Choose how many Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X to be rent on this day">
        <option>1</option>
        ...
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    16<br>
    <input type="checkbox" title="Activate this day" value="2013-07-16">
    <select title="Choose how many Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X to be rent on this day">
        <option>1</option>
        ...
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    17<br>
    <input type="checkbox" title="Activate this day" value="2013-07-17">
    <select title="Choose how many Vacuum Cleaner Brand-X to be rent on this day">
        <option>1</option>
        ...
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
</td>

...
```

Comment: I don't understand that calculation. Can you clarify it please? In particular I don't understand the explanation in the list.

Comment: The date for item 2 is the 16th, but you are charging him for the 15th to the 20th. For item 3, you have the number 5 in your array but you only want to charge for 3 days. The date for item 4 is the 18th, but you are listing 3 days (17th to 19th) and only charging for 2... I'm starting to see why you're finding it so difficult to write code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand $date array structure exactly but I think it should be an multidimensional array as shown below to calculate the total price as you desire

```
$dates['2013-07-15'] = array('item2', 'item1');
$dates['2013-07-16'] = array('item2', 'item1');
$dates['2013-07-17'] = array('item5', 'item4', 'item3', 'item2', 'item1');
$dates['2013-07-18'] = array('item3', 'item2', 'item1');
$dates['2013-07-19'] = array('item4', 'item3', 'item2', 'item1');
$dates['2013-07-20'] = array('item2', 'item1');
$dates['2013-07-21'] = array('item1');
```

Then calculate number of rent days for every item and calculate how many W and D is there.

```
$rent_days = array();
foreach($dates as $date => $items) {
  foreach($items as $item) {
    if(!isset($rent_days[$item]))
      $rent_days[$item] = 1;
    else $rent_days[$item]++;
  }
}

$w = 10.5; // as an example
$d = 2.3;

foreach($rent_days as $item => $n) {
  $w_num = floor($n/5); // number of weeks (namely, 5 consecutive days)
  $d_num = $n % 5; // number of days
  printf('Total price for %s: %.2f<br/>', $item, $w_num*$w + $d_num*$d);
}
```

And the output is

```
/*
Total price for item2: 12.80
Total price for item1: 15.10
Total price for item5: 2.30
Total price for item4: 4.60
Total price for item3: 6.90
*/
```